# Update json data in laravel 5.6

Tags: json, laravel, postgresql

Problem: Need to update json data in address names field.

**bookcontroller:**

```
public function edit(Book $book)
{
    return view('books.edit',compact('book'));
}
public function update(Request $request, Book $book)
{
    $book->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('books.index')->with('success','Book updated successfully');
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
 <form action="{{ route('books.update',$book->id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Name:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $book->name }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>


            <?php $num=1 ?>

        @foreach($book->address as $value)

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Address<?php echo  $num ?> :</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="addr" value="{{ $value['address'] }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Country <?php echo  $num ?>:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="country" value="{{ $value['country']}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Country">
                </div>
            </div>
                <?php  $num++ ?>
            @endforeach
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

How do I update json data?

I am using postgreSQL .......................................................................................................................................thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kristly D'sena, replace input name attribute "addr" to "addr[]" with a name of the array, Then and only then you will get multi-address in the array format in post method and then convert those addresses fields into the json using **json_encode**

Replace below script in your edit.blade.php file.

```
 @foreach($book->address as $value)
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Address<?php echo  $num ?> :</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="addr[]" value="{{ $value['address'] }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Country <?php echo  $num ?>:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="country[]" value="{{ $value['country']}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Country">
                </div>
            </div>
                <?php  $num++ ?>
            @endforeach
```

Do change in your update method in the bookcontroller.php file

```
public function update(Request $request, Book $book)
{

    $inputs = $request->all();
    $addr = ($request->addr);
    $country = ($request->country);
    $final_address = array();
    foreach ($addr as $key => $value) {
        $final_address[] = array('address' => $value, 'country'=>$country[$key] );
    }
    $inputs['address'] = json_encode($final_address);        
    $book->update($inputs);

    return redirect()->route('books.index')->with('success','Book updated successfully');
}
```

This way you will able updating address field json data.

Comment: i have this kind of json [{"address": "gdfg", "country": "fd"}, {"address": "dg", "country": "df"}, {"address": "gd", "country": "dfg"}] in address column

Comment: @KristlyD'sena I have updated my answer according to your json format, please try with the latest answer, I hope the updated answer will resolve your query.

Comment: Exception   :(  InvalidArgumentException Trailing data

Comment: @KristlyD'sena, I dont know table column name in which you are storing your full address detail, So i assumed column name "address" and kept $inputs['address'], Hense do replace your database column name in "$inputs['address']" key. Ex. If your column name is "address_detail" in the table then $inputs['address_detail'] = $final_address. I hope you will understand what i mean. :)

Comment: column name is address and when i use  var_dump($inputs['address']); this ,then the error  comes ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined index: address and array (size=5) and         var_dump($inputs);
 gives
  '_method' => string 'PUT' (length=3)
  'name' => string 'kajal' (length=5)
  'addr' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'gdfg' (length=4)
      1 => string 'dg' (length=2)
      2 => string 'gd' (length=2)
  'country' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'fd' (length=2)
      1 => string 'df' (length=2)
      2 => string 'dfg' (length=3)

Comment: @KristlyD'sena, I forgot to add "json_encode" method to the $final_address variable. I have updated my answer again, Please try with the latest answer.

Comment: still Exception :( InvalidArgumentException Trailing data

Comment: Can you please paste your complete InvalidArgumentExceptionerror code here to know exact error.

Comment: as i used postgreSQL and it not support updated_at column automatic i think because of  updated_at column error occurs